# Why does my EF4.1 relationship not get set to null upon assignment of a null value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

In my system I have tasks, which can optionally be assigned to contacts.  So in my business logic I have the following code:

```
 if (_contactChanged) { task.Contact = contact; }
```

If no contact was specified, the `contact` variable is null.  This is *supposed* to null out the contact relationship when I submit changes, however I have noticed this isn't happening 99% of the time I do it (I have seen it happen once, but not consistently after stepping through this code over and over).

When I debug, I have verified that `_contactChanged` is `true` and the inside code isn't getting hit.  However, after I step past `task.Contact = contact;` I notice that while `contact` is null, `task.Contact` is of type

```
{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies
.Contact_4DF70AA1AA8A6A94E9377F65D7B1DD3A837851FD3442862716FA7E966FFCBAB9}
```

and still has the previous data tied to it.

Why is the proxy not being set to null, and how can I get this to work properly?

Comment: Does the problem occure only if you debug the code or also in common execution? Do you also foreign key property defined?

Comment: It also occurs in regular code execution, I noticed it because the relationship wasn't being removed.  Foreign keys are defined properly.

Comment: I thought I was going nuts. I thought it was a model binding issue. Then I debugged and found this little gem happening. So weird. The equals operator must be overloaded for DyanmicProxies and it is not handling nulls correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow.  Great question.  I was able to confirm/reproduce this, **even if the referent is not a dynamic proxy**.  `t.Contact = null;` doesn't work!

The best answer I have so far is to say:

```
    context.Entry(task).Reference(t => t.Contact).CurrentValue = null;
```

I'm really hoping that there is a better way than this, because this is some pretty inconvenient syntax.

**UPDATE:**

This works:

```
    var task = context.Tasks
        .Where(...your condition here...)
        .Include(t => t.Contact)
        .First();

    task.Contact = null;
```

OR,

If you have a foreign key ID defined in your model (as in a nullable ContactId), this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: While driving home I actually had the same thought, that it was an issue of the relationship not being loaded yet due to lazy loading, and I had the same idea as your update.  Going to give it a try in the morning!

Comment: @KallDrexx - Sounds good.  Now that I think about it, I wonder if using CurrentValue is preferable.  From a performance standpoint, it has the advantage of fewer reads from the database (no need for a JOIN) and less tracking by the context (no entity loaded).  Some initial testing with SQL Profiler supports the database side of this claim.

Comment: `CurrentValue` isn't a good solution, as I would have to make some hacks to my UnitOfWork object that abstracts EF away.  However, your second solution works, and I set `ContactId` to null, and I seem to have no issues (without having extra data be eager loaded from the db)

Comment: +1 for `context.Entry(task).Reference(t => t.Contact).CurrentValue = null;`